# Run member function of an object in separate file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have separate files for functions and variables that I use in my program; a header file and an implementation file.

file.hpp:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

extern sf::Font sfFont;

#endif // FILE_H
```

file.cpp:

```
#include "file.hpp"

sf::Font sfFont;

sfFont.loadFromFile("ubuntu.ttf");  // <- error
```

My problem is on the line I've commented on. I except that line to run the member function "loadFromFile". Instead, I get the error: "error: ´sfFont´ does not name a type". How do I solve this?

As you can see I use the library SFML, but I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: every code that is executed, other than constructors of global variables, must be placed inside functions. The entry point of C++ code is function called main

Comment: What's the best solution then?

Comment: put it into a function, and call it from main afterwards

Comment: also, maybe reading a book about C++. This is not python, the script wont execute top-down automatically, as I said, it works from entry point(main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines such as

```
sfFont.loadFromFile("ubuntu.ttf");
```

are valid only inside other functions.

If you want to be able to make that function call, you can use a helper function to initialize a dummy variable and make the function call in the helper function.

```
static int init()
{
   sfFont.loadFromFile("ubuntu.ttf");
   return 0;
}

int dummy = init();
```

Comment: inline in my opinion is better option

Comment: @Creris, that is another option. I don't think one is better than the other.

Comment: static linkage can potentially generate different function bodies tho

Comment: @Creris, I don't get your drift. The function is in the .cpp file.